# Duplicate user "cryptoPolicy" in active directory 2012

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012, migration, duplicate

Im moving Windows Server 2012 Essentials to a new hardware using [this tutorial](https://www.server-essentials.com/support/articleid/107/migrate-windows-server-2012-r2-essentials-to-new-hardware) , in the best practice analyzer i found that i have 2 usernames with the same CN "CryptoPolicy" one inside Program Data/Microsoft/ADFS and the other inside Program Data/Microsoft/ADFS/62119230-1480-4a1f-a9f2-e2efdf889896, can i rename the second user without problems? or is it best to continue moving the domain with the duplicate names?

Regards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These CryptoPolicy contact objects are created during the configuration of ADFS server(s)/farm.  although they share the same name, they are not actually duplicates (which can be verified by comparing their different displayname and objectguid properties).

Assuming you have an existing/functioning ADFS environment, it is NOT SAFE to change these objects.